# Method is not allowed iis

Tags: python, windows, flask, post, iis

It was working fine yesterday when I setup my server to work with wfastcgi module after the server was restarted it somehow got broken.

Im trying to send post requests but all I get as response is method is not allowed

Comment: You have to provide some code. Let's see what are you doing here, please be clearer

Comment: `Method not allowed` is usually issued when you e.g. send a `post` request to an endpoint, but the endpoint is only configured for `get` requests.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue you could try to follow the below steps:

Remove web dev module from the site

1. Open iis manager select your site.
2. Double click "Handler Mappings"
3. Scroll down and select the WebDav module. Right-click on it and remove it.

[image]

another thing is to make sure your python flask handler verb section select "all verb"

[image]